# Compute euclidean distance for PCA in R

Tags: r, pca, euclidean-distance

I did a PCA (using eigenvalue and smartPCA) and now I am trying to compute the Euclidean distance to one population. For example , in this dataset, I would want to compute in R the Euclidean distance of all population to population 6.

```
Individual    PCA1    PCA2    PCA3    PCA4    PCA5    PCA6   PCA7   PCA8    PCA8   PCA10  
1: Pop1 0.0346  0.0095 -0.0022  -0.0018 -0.0033  0.0002 0.0042 -0.0003  0.0028  0.0268  
2: Pop2 0.0370  0.0095 -0.0027  0.0015 -0.0027 -0.0024  0.0038  0.0012  0.0053  0.0210  
3: Pop3 0.0379  0.0100 -0.0030  0.0021 -0.0017 -0.0043 0.0033  0.0005  0.0036  0.0144   
4: Pop4 0.0352  0.0092 -0.0031 -0.0021 -0.0029 -0.0005. 0.0038 -0.0003  0.0047  0.0349   
5: Pop5 0.0342  0.0089 -0.0027 -0.0013 -0.0031 -0.0008 0.0032 -0.0017 -0.0009  0.0265
6: Pop6 0.0342  -0.0524 -0.0503 -0.1028 -0.4785 -0.0244  0.0279 0.0038 -0.0264 -0.0022 -0.0265
```

I found a thread on how to do it in Python but can't find it in R ! I tried `dist()` but the I don't understand the output or how to compare to only one population (I have 500+ population in total)

Thanks !

Comment: can you show an example of your data frame? you can convert the distance object to a matrix using ```as.matrix(dist(..))``` and this will be pairwise distance between each row

Comment: Thanks a lot ! My matrix looks like the subsample I posted in the original post but I do think, with your helps, I achieved to do what I want. I want to add another column with their respective distance to Pop6. If I understand your comment correctly, this  should do what I want (dt is my data.table):

`dist(dt[,2:11],method = "euclidean");
dt[, Distance:= as.matrix(dt)[,6]]`

Thanks a lot !!!

Comment: Try the `rdist()` function in package `fields`. It will let you compute Euclidean distances between a vector and a matrix.